# grep and awk to ignore special chars and spaces and search in 2 files

Tags: awk

I have 2 lists ...

a.txt:

```
I am a bad wolf (2015)  
you are a bad wolf (2020)  
we all - are bad wolf (1123)  
you are a bad wolf 2 (2021)
```

b.txt:

```
I am - a bad wolf (2015)  
you are abad wolf (2019)
```

I would like the output file c.c to contain JUST the unique lines from a.txt NOT present in b.txt and also ignore the numbers in the brackets.

c.txt :

```
we all - are bad wolf (1123)  
you are a bad wolf 2 (2021)
```

I've tried `grep -ixvf a.txt b.txt > c.txt`

but it does not ignore those spaces and special chars..

I'm guessing this will require some sort of sed (remove special chars) | grep ...

Any help is appriciated...

Comment: Please do wrap your samples/codes in CODE TAGS .

Comment: If you're `guessing this will require some sort of sed` then it would have made sense to tag your question with sed. In reality the right solution won't use sed or grep since you're not trying to do `s/old/new/` (what sed is the right tool for) nor `g/re/p` (what grep is the right tool for), it'll use awk or equivalent so I'm replacing the grep tag with awk.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "special chars" you mean anything that isn't typically considered word-constituent, i.e. alpha-numeric or underscore:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    key = $0
    gsub(/[^[:alnum:]_]|\([^()]+)/,"",key)
}
NR==FNR {
    a[key] = (key in a ? a[key] ORS : "") $0
    next
}
!(key in a)
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk b.txt a.txt
we all - are bad wolf (1123)
you are a bad wolf 2 (2021)
```